# Ввод и сравнение чисел в Java (Eclipse)

Tags: java, eclipse

Добрый день.  Работаю в Eclipse.

Этот участок кода (внизу) ведет себя "необычно" при выполнении из самого IDE.
Сначала появляется строчка "Введите год".
Ввожу год - число "2011". В отладке стоит значение переменной "50"  (? я же ввел 2011?).
Далее, строчки с System.in.read() пропускаются (не выполняются), а в значение переменных `oMonth` и `oDays` записано соовтетственно "48" и "49". (? откуда система взяла эти числа?). Естественное, результат вычислений ошибочный.

Этот участок кода должен получить значение года/месяца/числа. Потом имдет сравнение текущие год/месяц/число.

```
    System.out.println("\tВведите год");
int oYear = System.in.read();       
    System.out.println("\tМесяц:");
int oMonth = System.in.read();
    System.out.println("\tЧисло:");
int oDays = System.in.read();
```

**Подскажите пожалуйста, где я неправ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не стоит так считывать данные, используйте Scanner или StringTokenizer.
Прочитайте внимательно в документации, что делает io.read(), поймёте природу ошибки и откуда вообще эти магические числа.

Answer (score 4):

int oYear=Integer.parseInt(System.in.readLine());

Comment: Спасибо, заработало :)

Answer (score 2):

```
private static int input()
    {
        try
        {
            java.io.BufferedReader reader = new java.io.BufferedReader(new java.io.InputStreamReader(System.in));
            return reader.readInt();
        }
        catch (IOException ioe)
        {
            System.err.println("Problem reading from the keyboard, returning null");
            // Ignore this and return null
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

и используйте в виде `year = input();`